# Web page auto dimming when hover on main menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento, magento-1.9

I have a webpage running magento and it is using vmegamenu.
Now my customer wants to dim the page when someone is hovering on the main menu or the dropdown box.
Example : http://jsfiddle.net/rkLL6yd8/3/

CSS

```
.link {
  z-index: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.dim {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -6;
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('.link').hover(function() {
  $('.dim').fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
  $('.dim').fadeOut(200);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="dim"></div>
<ul>
  <div class="link">
    <li>Home</li>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    <li>Main</li>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    <li>Home</li>
  </div>
  <div class="link">
    <li>Home</li>
  </div>
</ul>

Some text here
```

The website is here : www.profileauto.co.uk

I have the current files for vmegamenu

vmegamenu.phtml

```
<div class="nav-vcontainer hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <div class="vmegamenu-title"><h2><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><?php echo $this->__('Product Categories') ?></h2></div>
        <div class="vmegamenu-contain">
            <div id="nav_vmegamenu" class="nav_vmegamenu">
                <?php $megamenu =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('megamenu/megamenu'); ?>       
                <?php //echo $megamenu->drawMegamenuHome(); ?>
                <?php echo $megamenu->drawMegamenuMain(); ?>        
                <?php //echo $megamenu->drawMegamenuExtra(); ?>
                <?php //echo $megamenu->drawMegamenuLink(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var MEGAMENU_EFFECT = <?php echo (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/general/effect')?>;

        //]]>
    </script> 

</div>
```

And this file

vmegamenu.css

```
.nav-vcontainer {
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -88px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.catalog-category-view .main .nav-vcontainer,
.catalog-product-view .main .nav-vcontainer {
  margin-top: -58px;
}
.cms-index-index .nav-vcontainer {
  margin: -48px 0 0 ;
}
.nav-inner {
  position:relative;
}
.vmegamenu-contain { border: 1px solid #f0f0f0; border-top: 0; margin: 0 -1px;}
.nav-vcontainer:hover .vmegamenu-contain { display: block;}
.nav-vcontainer .vmegamenu-title {   }
.nav-vcontainer .vmegamenu-title h2 { color: #fff; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 15px; background: #181818; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; font-family: Montserrat; height: 48px;}
.nav-vcontainer .vmegamenu-title h2 i { margin-top: 2px; font-size: 14px; float: right;}

.nav_vmegamenu {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 0;

}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top { position: relative;}
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .hot,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .new {
  display: none;
}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu { position:relative; padding: 0; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top a {
    padding: 11px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #555;
    border: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url(../images/icon-menu.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 45px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-1 .level-top a { border: 0; background-position: 15px 18px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-2 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -36px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-3 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -86px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-4 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -137px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-5 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -190px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-6 .level-top a { background-position: 17px -242px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-7 .level-top a { background-position: 17px -294px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-8 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -346px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-9 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -398px; }
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.nav-10 .level-top a { background-position: 15px -450px; }


.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top a > .fa,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top span.block-title > .fa {
    position: absolute; right: 15px; top: 20px;

}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.megamenu_no_child .level-top a >.fa { display: none;}
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top a .fa-angle-down:before {
  content: "\f0da";
  color: #bababa;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu div.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 100% !important;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #eee;*/
    border-top: 0;
    width: 935px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu .block1 {
   padding: 25px;
}
.nav_vmegamenu .block2 {

}

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu:hover div.dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.active .level-top a,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.act .level-top a,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.active .level-top span.block-title,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top a:hover,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top span.block-title:hover,
.nav_vmegamenu #pt_menu_link ul li a.act,
.nav_vmegamenu #pt_menu_link ul li a:hover,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.act {
    background-color: #00adee;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top a:hover .fa-angle-down:before,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.active .level-top a .fa:before,
.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu.act .level-top a .fa:before{
  color: #fff;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.dropdown a {
    display:block;
    line-height: 30px;
}


.nav_vmegamenu .itemMenu h4.level1,
.nav_vmegamenu .itemMenu a.level1{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

.megamenu .itemMenu a.level2:before,
.megamenu .itemMenu a.level3:before,
.megamenu .itemMenu a.level4:before{
  content:"\f111";
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #bababa;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;

}
.megamenu .itemMenu a:hover:before {
  content: "";
  margin: 0;
}

.megamenu .itemMenu a.level2:hover,
.megamenu .itemMenu a.level3:hover,
.megamenu .itemMenu a.level4:hover {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu .itemSubMenu a.itemMenuName {
    color: #555555;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.column {
    float:left;
    width:200px; /* column width */
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu div.column.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.itemSubMenu {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav_vmegamenu .block2{
    float: left;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.dropdown .block1{
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.dropdown .block1 .column{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.nav_vmegamenu div.dropdown .blockright img{
    max-width: 100%;
} 

.nav_vmegamenu div.megamenu .level-top p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav_vmegamenu #pt_menu_link{
    padding: 0;
}
.nav_vmegamenu #pt_menu_link .level-top ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_vmegamenu #pt_menu_link .level-top ul li a{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
}
.nav_vmegamenu .clearBoth {
    clear:both;
}
```

I am trying to achive what this website has done.

www.johnlewis.co.uk
When you hover on the main menu all the page is dim and dark and only the main menu and drop down is visible.

Please help.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: and again and again and again, JAVA is NOT the same as JavaScript, this is not JAVA!

Comment: It looks like you have already cracked that nut.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. i Dont know how to build that small example in to the website. That is the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Magento 3rd party module support is best asked from the party that created the module. If it has to be paid for, or has to be hunted down for installation, the number of people who will be able to answer vastly narrows. Also, Magento development questions best asked over in magento.stackexchange.

Comment: guys all i am asking is some guidance how to build that example in to the two files i have listed. nothing else. no magento 3rd party apps.